# Modern Browser with a feature to disable SNI

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, firewall, blocking

I want to know if there is any modern client browser which allows disabling the SNI ([server name indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)) extension of the TLS.

I want to know because it seems that my ISP blocks some HTTPS websites depending on the SNI feature because the server name is sent in [plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38727920/4040525).

[This paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01202712/document) provides more insight but their tool to disable SNI-based filtering is outdated.

(NB: I know that I can just use VPN. I know that a lot of websites won't work if I don't use SNI. Moreover, I don't want to install old outdated browsers which didn't have SNI, eg: Firefox 1.5 or chrome 5.7)

Comment: It's possible to circumvent SNI based filtering - https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01202712/document - but I don't know of any tool or browser extension that does it.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I have already read their paper. They had a tool (firefox extension) called escape but it is outdated

Comment: Wait till TLS1.3 would be widely implemented...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently firefox added [ESNI](https://blog.cloudflare.com/encrypted-sni/) support as an experimental feature. This means that on sites that support it (over TLS1.3), the browser will send encrypted server name during handshake.

Many of the sites behind cloudflare currently support it (some are still using tls1.2 though).

(Un)fortunately(?) currently ESNI on firefox is paired with [DoH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS), meaning you should also enable [trr](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Trusted_Recursive_Resolver) on the browser. See [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1558003)

To enable ESNI on firefox:

- `about:config`

  - `network.trr.mode: 2`
  - `network.trr.uri: https://dns.google/dns-query` (the default did not work for me)
  - `network.security.esni.enabled: true`
- Restart
- Validate whether ESNI is enabled in your browser: https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/encrypted-sni/
- Check whther the site you want to access supports tls1.3 (then there is a high chance that it will also support esni): https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test
- Make some requests
- `about:networking#dns`

  - Can check whether any requests use ESNI

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @reinierpost "...because it seems that my ISP blocks some HTTPS websites depending on the SNI feature because the server name is sent in plain text". ESNI does not send server name in plain text.

Comment: I see. I came here because I wanted an answer to the actual question being asked.

Comment: I, too, came here looking for a way to **disable** SNI. Not _encrypt_ it in _some_ cases for websites served over _one particular CDN_.